# 2-competitiveness of MTF

Tags: algorithm, list

I know how MTF is 2-competitive if we assume the optimal algorithm OPT to be allowed to:

1. access the kth element in a list at cost k,
2. choose to move this kth element anywhere closer to the front of the list for free,
3. swap adjacent elements in the list for cost 1.

The proof is standard and found everywhere on the web. How does the proof change, however, when the 3rd operation is not allowed? More specifically, none of MTF and OPT are allowed paid swaps: the only operation allowed is 1 and 2 for OPT, and 1 and a free move-to-front for MTF.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proof doesn't change – the algorithm is not affected, and the adversary is weaker. MTF is still only 2-competitive in the restricted setting, as there exists a family of access sequences with ratio 2 - o(1) where OPT doesn't move elements at all.

Comment: Thank you. Couple of points:

1. Could you clarify what you mean by "with ratio 2 - o(1)"?

2. I see how the standard proof would work, but intuitively, why is the adversary weaker? It seems that we are restricting its abilities, or am I missing something?

Comment: The family of examples I'm thinking of queries MTF's last element repeatedly. The competitive ratio is always better than 2, but no number less than 2 is an upper bound. Yes, we are restricting the adversary's abilities, so there are no new cases to consider.